# Why can' t I Convert SparseArray to Array?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I started using the Android SparseArray recently in place of in place of ArrayList for small numbers of items. I am wondering why it does not contain a toArray() method like a normal ArrayList? It contains a private objects array for values but no way of returning them. It seems to me that this would be a useful method to have as ArrayList to array conversions are common occurrences in Android. I am assuming that because of the way hashing works it would return an array with empty slots?

My second question is, what would be the most efficient way to convert a SparseArray to a normal Object array?

Comment: Probably best to convert from SparseArray to ArrayList to an Array.

Comment: Im going to have to do that. It just seems like an unnecessary manual step.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer the title of your question, there is no method for this because the SparseArray is not an array, it is in fact an optimization of a HashMap, binding arbitrary integers to arbitrary values. The optimization lies in the fact that it uses no boxing/unboxing where a HashMap would.

Then the second part, how you should convert it to an array, I would recommend determining the largest array index using size() and `keyAt(index)`, and then allocating an array of the appropriate size, and finally copying all values using the `get(index, default)` method with a sensible default.

Answer (score 0):

theres no such method to do that, but you can convert the SparseArray iterating :

```
public static <C> List<C> ConvertToList(SparseArray<C> sparseArray) {
    if (sparseArray == null) return null;
    List<C> arrayList = new ArrayList<C>(sparseArray.size());

    for (int i = 0; i < sparseArray.size(); i++)
        arrayList.add(sparseArray.valueAt(i));
    return arrayList;
}
```

Comment: What does "<C>" mean here?

Comment: data type that you pass in SparseArray

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin version:

```
    private inline fun <reified VALUE> SparseArray<VALUE>.toArrayOrNull(): Array<VALUE>? {
        return if (isNotEmpty()) {
            Array<VALUE>(size()) { index -> this[index] }
        } else {
            null
        }
    }
```